# Selecting and deseleting all checkboxes using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array state for some checkboxes where I am catching the labels for those that are true (checked). Must ignore the false.

I am able to generate a list of checked checkboxes thanks to some of you in another thread. But I'm hitting another wall with the select all toggle.

```
  const handleSwitch = (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked) {
      setActive(true);
      const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map(element => element.checked = true);
      setCheckedState([...updatedCheckedState]);   
    } else {      
      setActive(false)
      const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map(element => element.checked = false);
      setCheckedState([...updatedCheckedState]);   
    }
  }
```

This function above in particular. Likewise, if I manually check all of the checkboxes inside, it needs to know that all are selescted and make the active state = true. If I can get help with at least the first part, I'm confident I can solve the other part myself.

Here's a [**sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-chihiro-s7orvp) if you want to mess around with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sandbox is quite broken. The way you are tracking checked state is internally inconsistent.)

The main culprits (in Filter.js) are:

- on line 119, you treat checkedState like a dictionary, but in `handleSwitch` and `handleOnChange` you treat it like an array (but the logic inside is still non-functional for the array approach as far as I can tell.

  - if you want it to be an array, let it be a string-valued "checkedLabels" array, and set `checked` on your checkbox component to `checkedLabels.includes(item.label)`
  - if you want it to be a dictionary:

    - `handleOnChange` needs to simply toggle the currently clicked element, like so `[e.target.name]: !checkedState[e.target.name]`
    - `handleSwitch` needs to add an entry for every element in `data`, set to `true` or `false` as appropriate.

Example ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-microservice-73px3f?file=/src/Filter.js)):

```
const handleSwitch = (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    setActive(true);
    setCheckedState(
      Object.fromEntries(data.map((item) => [item.label.toLowerCase(), true]))
    );
  } else {
    setActive(false);
    setCheckedState({});
  }
};

const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  setCheckedState({
    ...checkedState,
    [e.target.name]: !checkedState[e.target.name]
  });
};

<CustomCheckbox
  size="small"
  name={item.label.toLowerCase()}
  checked={checkedState[item.label.toLowerCase()] ?? false}
  onChange={handleOnChange}
/>
```

**EDIT from OP**
I tweaked the hnadleOnChange function to

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    setCheckedState({
      ...checkedState,
      [e.target.name]: !checkedState[e.target.name]
    });
  } else {
    const updatedCheckedState = {...checkedState};
    delete updatedCheckedState[e.target.name];
    setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);   
  }
};
```

Before, it allowed for false values to be added when you unchecked a previously checked checkbox. This removes it

---

Edit: To do this with an array, you'll want to add to the array when checking, and remove from it when un-checking. Then do an `includes` to see if an individual checkbox should be checked.

Also, you can do a simple `setActive(newCheckedItemLabels.length === data.length);` in the `handleOnChange` to achieve your other requirement.

[This codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dewdney-ld06w3?file=/src/Filter.js) does everything you need with arrays instead of objects.

Notably:

```
  const [checkedItemLabels, setCheckedItemLabels] = useState([]);

  const handleSwitch = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setActive(true);
      setCheckedItemLabels(data.map((item) => item.label.toLowerCase()));
    } else {
      setActive(false);
      setCheckedItemLabels([]);
    }
  };

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const newCheckedItemLabels = checkedItemLabels.includes(e.target.name)
      ? checkedItemLabels.filter((label) => label !== e.target.name)
      : [...checkedItemLabels, e.target.name];
    setCheckedItemLabels(newCheckedItemLabels);
    setActive(newCheckedItemLabels.length === data.length);
  };
    <CustomCheckbox
      size="small"
      name={item.label.toLowerCase()}
      checked={checkedItemLabels.includes(
        item.label.toLowerCase()
      )}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
```

Comment: this is great but it returns an object. I need to return an array. Son instead of `{action: true,  horror: true, comedy: true …}`, I need `['action',  'horror', 'comedy', …}`. Also, the handleOnChange in your response adds false values to the object. if you check and then uncheck it, it adds it anyway as false, like this `{action: true,  horror: false, comedy: true …}`. I can't have false values. Sorry if I confused you

Comment: I tweaked the handleOnChange to `const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setCheckedState({
        ...checkedState,
        [e.target.name]: !checkedState[e.target.name]
      });
    } else {
      const updatedCheckedState = {...checkedState};
      delete updatedCheckedState[e.target.name];
      setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);   
    }
  };`

Comment: It works, but I'd be more comfortable if this worked as an array

Comment: Edited to show how to do this with arrays. [Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dewdney-ld06w3?file=/src/Filter.js)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @JohnPaulR answer. You can add useEffect hoot to achieve additional requirements you have.

> if I manually check all of the checkboxes inside, it needs to know that all are selected and make the active state = true.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkedTotal = Object.keys(checkedState).reduce((count, key) => {
      if (checkedState[key]) {
        return count + 1;
      }
    }, 0);
    setActive(data.length === checkedTotal);
  }, [checkedState]);
```

A full working example https://codesandbox.io/s/still-water-btyoly

Comment: Nice catch! Though the other response was more complete. it didn't address this. The other response (and this one) handle this entire collection as an Object list. But I need to handle it as an array. So instead of  `{action: true,  horror: true, comedy: true …}` as a result, I need `['action',  'horror', 'comedy', …]`.